# How to convert the sunset UNIX timestamp from OpenWeather API to local time using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, api, date

I'm using the OpenWeather API to get the sunset time for a specific city. The API returns the sunset time as a UNIX timestamp, and I want to convert this timestamp into the local time of the specific city using JavaScript.

```
  "name": "Mountain View"
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 5122,
    "country": "US",
    "sunrise": 1681565616,
    "sunset": 1681612963
  },
  "timezone": -25200,
```

I've tried creating a new Date object using the sunset timestamp like this:

```
var sunsetTimestamp = 1681612963;
var sunsetDate = new Date(sunsetTimestamp * 1000);
console.log(sunsetDate)
```

However, this doesn't give me the correct local time of sunset.

Comment: so what time does it give you?

Comment: How do you know the timezone ("local time") of the respective city?

Comment: multiply sunsetTimestamp with 1000

Comment: If you make a Date instance with one of those numbers multiplied by 1000 (to make it a millisecond timestamp), and then convert the Date instance to a string, by default you will get the date/time in your local time zone.

Comment: @TatulMkrtchyan That might give you the appropriate `Date` object for the unix timestamp, but still not the correct local time in that city

Comment: Right, the OP will need to know the offset from UTC for the city involved.

Comment: @Bergi There is a value of -25200 in the "timezone" property in the API response

Comment: @William what will be the correct local time? Is there 7 hours difference?

Comment: @William Please [edit] your question to include such vital information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add sunsetTimestamp to timezone before creating the date.  The date it creates doesn't equal the UTC date of Mountain View at sunset, but it does output the timezone-adjusted value for the sunset.

```js
var sunsetTimestamp = 1681612963;
var timezone = -25200;
var sunsetDate = new Date((sunsetTimestamp + timezone) * 1000);
console.log(sunsetDate)
```

Comment: Since this is pretending to be a local time for the related place name, the last line should be `sunsetDate.toISOString().substring(0,23)` to emulate a local timestamp.